# Tablesorter grouping widget with filtering issue

Tags: tablesorter

I am using the table sorter grouping widget along with the filtering enabled. When I filter on a particular column and enter say 123 then filtering is working fine.. but when I just click any other filter textbox in a different column the grouping disappears and again if I sort or remover the text the grouping comes back.

Can anyone please let me know what is causing the grouping to be lost when the user has entered a filter text in a column and when he just clicks any other filter textbox the grouping is lost

Comment: Are you using the latest version?... Previous versions did have [an issue](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/422) with that combo.

Comment: This are the files I am using :Tablesorter Grouping widget - updated 11/25/2013 
TableSorter 2.14.5 - Client-side table sorting with ease!
TableSorter 2.8+ widgets - updated 12/16/2013 (v2.14.5)
Input & select parsers for jQuery 1.7+ & tablesorter 2.7.11+

Comment: I checked the files used in this demo http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-grouping-filter-childrows.html and i have all the files that are used here.

Comment: as you had explained in another post that we use the $('table[id$="casesTable"]').trigger('applyWidgets'); to refresh the table so , to sort this problem can we call this script on the onClick event of the filters textbox ?

Comment: I'm still not seeing what you are describing... can you [update this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/2054/) to replicate this problem.

Comment: yes i will once again try with the latest files from the demo and check .. in case the problem still persists then I will create a jsfiddle demo.. Thanks

Comment: I have managed to make a workaround.. but without your help all this time it would had been impossible .. here is the code `code`//add the tablesorter trigger to all the search filters so that the grouping does not get lost
       $('input[type=search]').each(function() {
            {
                    $(this).click(function() {
                         $('table[id$="casesTable"]').trigger('applyWidgets');
                });
            }
        });